# Net momentum confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors

When a body is moving with some velocity, the velocity can be resolved into two components. Does this apply to momentum? For example, consider two bodies moving with velocities $u_1$ and $u_2$ making an angle of 30 degrees with each other. Will the net momentum be something like finding the resultant of these two momentum like what we do to regular vectors?

Answer (score 1):

As momentum is a vector, it can be treated as such; therefore, your usual business with components and resultants applies.

Comment: but what would be the physical meaning of this?For example:When an object is at rest is introduced to a vertical force of 10N and horizontal force of 10N,it will displace making an angle 45 degrees with the horizontal.But,what about this one?

Answer (score 0):

Since momentum is defined as $\textbf{p} = m \textbf{v}$, and as you said the velocity $\textbf{v}$ is a vector, for the rules of vector spaces  (specifically [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication)), $\textbf{p}$ is itself a vector.

Therefore usual vector operations are perfectly legitimate with $\textbf{p}$ too, including the ones you referred to.

Comment: My teacher was solving a problem for particle explosion where two particles decayed and exploded in directions 30 degrees from each other.As per conservtion of linear momentum he wrote 0=m1u1+m2u2?Is he correct and he is missing the vector bussines here?

Comment: @SurazBasnet 0=m1u1+m2u2 can't be correct (if is to be interpreted as it is, without vector signs); since, as I said, velocity is a vector, the correct equation for the conservation of momentum in a case like this (where $\textbf{u}_1$ is not parallel to $\textbf{u}_2$) is $\textbf{0} = m_1 \textbf{u}_1 + \textbf{u}_2$

Comment: where is m2 in your equation?

Comment: Well, in this particular case, since the sum of the individual momentum components must be zero, the two vectors must be collinear and the vector equation can indeed be reduced to the scalar equation your teacher wrote down. All this means is that you're using a coordinate system aligned with the velocity vectors, and the equation your teacher wrote down then becomes an equation for the non-zero components of the two vectors in the chosen coordinate system. Of course, this reduction of the vector equation to a scalar equation will not be possible, in general, if there's more than two particles